# How do I subclass a JSON schema

Tags: jsonschema

## How do I subclass in JSON-Schema?

First I restrict myself to draft-07, because that's all I can find implementations of.

The naive way to do sub-classing is described in

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending

But this works poorly with 'additionalProperties': false?

Why bother with
additionalProperties': false?

Without it - nearly any random garbage input json will be considered valid, since all the
'error' (mistaken json) will just be considered 'additionalProperties'.

Recapping https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending

- use allOf(baseClass)
- then add your own properties

The problem with this - is that it doesn't work with 'additionalProperties' (because of
unclear but appantly unfortunate definitions of additionalProperties that it ONLY applies
to locally defined (in that sub-schema) properties, so one or the other schema will fail validation.

Alternative Approaches:

- meta languages/interpretters layered on top of JSONSchema
  (such as https://github.com/mokkabonna/json-schema-merge-allof)

  This is not a good choice as the scehma can only be used from javascript (or the
  language of that meta processor). And not easily interoperable with other tools
- https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/wiki/v5%3A-merge
- An alternative I will propose as a 'solution' / answer

Comment: You should switch to an implementation supporting draft-2019-09 if you can, because this is exactly why `unevaluatedProperties` (and `$recursiveRef`) were added.

Comment: OK - I'm sold! which one do you recommend for Python? - And by the way, though thats a GREAT answer (happy this has been solved in 2019-09) - I didn't find any documentation indicating that. In fact, the docs on https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending  maybe should be updated to reflect this?

Comment: @lewis We would love to complely overhaul the understanding site with nice documentation, but it all takes time. None of us get paid to work on JSON Schema during work hours. Pull Requests welcome! As an aside, we have a great and active slack community should you want to discuss things =]

Comment: I did NOT mean to complain about your volunteer work. I do my own open source projects, and I appreciate it when people post (thoughtful) complaints about lacking in documentation. We all want the work we do to be widely used and accessible.  I'm too naive about JSONSchema to be a useful contributer at this point, but that could change. I will give your slack channel a shot; just joined. THANKS

Comment: @lewis it doesn't look like there is a draft-2019-09 implementation for python yet -- https://json-schema.org/implementations.html -- but I can recommend the Perl implementation authored by Yours Truly :D

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with that, especially since I had to use legacy versions of JSON Schema. And I found that the solution is a tiny bit verbose but quite easy to read and understand.

Let's say that you want describe that kind of type:

```
interface Book {
  pageCount: number
}

interface Comic extends Book {
  imageCount: number
}

interface Encyclopedia extends Book {
  volumeCount: number
}

// This is the schema I want to represent:
type ComicOrEncyclopedia = Comic | Encyclopedia
```

Here is how I can **both** handle polymorphism and forbid any extra-prop (while obviously enforcing inherited types in the "child" definitions):

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "bookDefinition": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "imageCount": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "pageCount": {
          "type": "number"
        },
        "volumeCount": {
          "type": "number"
        }
      }
    },

    "comicDefinition": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/bookDefinition" }],
      "properties": {
        "imageCount": {},
        "pageCount": {},
        "volumeCount": {
          "not": {}
        }
      },
      "required": ["imageCount", "pageCount"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "encyclopediaDefinition": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/bookDefinition" }],
      "properties": {
        "imageCount": {
          "not": {}
        },
        "pageCount": {},
        "volumeCount": {}
      },
      "required": ["pageCount", "volumeCount"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/comicDefinition" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/encyclopediaDefinition" }]
}
```

Comment: Works great for me in validation! I didn't have to define non-shared attributes in bookDefinition (imageCount, volumeCount), and I didn't have to use the exclusion clauses, e.g. `volumeCount: {not:{}}`. I'm using draft 7 schema. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a GREAT answer. But until the definition of JSONSchema is improved (or someone provides a better answer) - this is what I've come up with as workable.

Basically, you define two copies of each type, the first with all the details but no additionalProperties: false flag. Then second, REFERENCING the first, but with the 'additionalProperties: false' set.

The first you can think of as an 'abstract class' and the second as a 'concrete class'.

Then, to 'subclass', you use the https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending approach, but referencing the ABSTRACT class, and then add the 'additionalProperties: false'. SADLY, to make this work, you must also REPEAT all the inherited properties (but no need to include their type info - just their names) - due to the sad choice for how JSONSchema draft 7 appears to interpret additionalProperties.

An EXAMPLE - based on https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending should help:

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/3fhU3O1X

(reproduced here in case other site
/link not permanant/reliable)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://TEST",
  "definitions": {
    "interface-address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "city": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "state": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    },
    "concrete-address": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/interface-address"
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {},
        "city": {},
        "state": {}
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    "in-another-file-subclass-address": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/interface-address"
        }
      ],
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "street_address": {},
        "city": {},
        "state": {},
        "type": {
          "enum": ["residential", "business"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["type"]
    },
    "test-of-address-schemas": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "interface-address-allows-bad-fields": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/interface-address"
        },
        "use-concrete-address-to-only-admit-legit-addresses-without-extra-crap": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/concrete-address"
        },
        "still-can-subclass-using-interface-not-concrete": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/in-another-file-subclass-address"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/test-of-address-schemas"
    }
  ]
}
```

and example document:

```
{
   "interface-address-allows-bad-fields":{
      "street_address":"s",
      "city":"s",
      "state":"s",
      "allow-bad-fields-this-is-why-we-need-additionalProperties":"s"
   },
   "use-concrete-address-to-only-admit-legit-addresses-without-extra-crap":{
      "street_address":"s",
      "city":"s",
      "state":"s"
   },
   "still-can-subclass-using-interface-not-concrete":{
      "street_address":"s",
      "city":"s",
      "state":"s",
      "type":"business"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I subclass in JSON-Schema?

You don't, because JSON Schema is not object oriented and schemas are not classes. JSON Schema is designed for validation. A schema is a collection of constraints.

But, let's look at it from an OO perspective anyway.

### Composition over inheritance

The first thing to note is that JSON Schema doesn't support an analog to inheritance. You might be familiar with the old OO wisdom, "composition over inheritance". The Go language, chooses not to support inheritance at all, so JSON Schema is in good company with that approach. If you build your system using only composition, you will have no issues with `"additionalProperties": false`.

### Polymorphism

Let's say that thinking in terms of composition is too foreign (it takes time to learn to think differently) or you don't have control over how your types are designed. For whatever reason, you need to model your data using inheritance, you can use the `allOf` pattern you're familiar with. The `allOf` pattern isn't quite the same as inheritance, but it's the closest you're going to get.

As you've noted, `"additionalProperties": false` wreaks havoc in conjunction with the `allOf` pattern. So, why should you leave this out? The OO answer is polymorphism. Let's say you have a "Person" type and a "Student" type that extends "Person". If you have a Student, you should be able to pass it to a method that accepts a Person. It doesn't matter that Student has a few properties that Person doesn't, when it's being used as a Person, the extra properties are simply ignored. If you use `"additionalProperties": false`, your types can't be polymorphic.

---

None of this is the kind of solution you are asking for, but hopefully it gives you a different perspective to consider alternatives to solve your problem in different way that is more idiomatic for JSON Schema.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer! However, you presume aggregation is better than polymorphism and denigrate OO by labeling it 'old'. I'm quite open minded to arguments against OO (and I certainly am old), but years of experience leaves me seeing the power of OO modeling, and especially polymorphism. The GIST of my question is how to use JSONSchema to support OO modeling. I agree JSONSchema doesnt do a good job supporting OO. I HOPE that improves over time. And my answer below is an attempt to show how those who DO believe in OO can still leverage JSONSchema tools.

Comment: I was not at all denigrating OO. I was pointing out that JSON Schema is not designed to be an OO type system and if you treat it that way, you will always be cutting against the grain. I was not calling OO old, I was calling the "composition over inheritance" adage a wise way to approach OO that dates back to when OO was still young. It originates from the Gang of Four Design Patterns book (1995). Nothing about that statement was intended to be derogatory.

Comment: I was saying that composition is better than inheritance, not better than polymorphism. Polymorphism is very powerful and useful. I argue against using `"additionalProperties": false`even when strictly using composition because it enables polymorphism.

Comment: If you really want to both extend your types and don't want them to be polymorphic, draft 2019-09 introduces `unevaluatedProperties` which works just like `additionalProperties` except that it can take sub-schemas into account. `unevaluatedProperties` is not easy to implement so tooling has been slow to support it, but things are happening quickly on that front recently. There are implementations in C#, Java, JavaScript, and Perl, with support in the works in several other languages. If there isn't an implementation that supports draft 2019-09 in your language yet, there likely will be soon.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications! But as near as I can tell, if you omit "additionalProperties": false (in draft7 at least) - you might as well not use schema. 95% (a number pulled out of thin air) of mistakes/bad json just get ignored/go unreported, because they are assumed to be 'new properties'. Like if you have a space in a name, or different case - just ignored content. That makes json schema nearly useless UNLESS you specify additionalProperties (or so it would appear to this naive user).

Comment: And not to be obtuse, but in json shema - how do you do polymorphism OTHER than by inheritance? I now just define schema for my 'INTERFACES' - and 'subclass' to define 'subtypes' of those interfaces. Maybe you mean polymorphism is good so long as you dont have subtypes? Or maybe this is a linguistic thing where you use inheritance to refer to soemthing about inherited implementation rathan than subtyped interfaces?

Comment: The only time leaving out `"additionalProperties": false` leads to the possibility of some typos getting ignored is with optional properties. Otherwise the `required` keyword will catch the typo. But, even if all of your properties are optional, typos must be closer to 5% of mistakes than 95%. I think what's really needed in these cases is a linter to warn you that something is technically correct, but probably not what you intended.

Comment: Discussing this in terms of class-based type systems is tough because a schema is not a class and JSON Schema is not a type system. When I talk about polymorphism in this context, I'm referring to the kind you see in a duck typing system. If a function takes an object and uses properties A and B, then an object that has properties A, B, and C can be passed to that function. ABC might be a subtype of AB by mathematical deduction, but they are not necessarily named types part of a type system. Type inheritance is a mechanism for defining a type. Polymorphism doesn't require defined types.

Comment: In my experience, you have the 95% and 5% cases backwards. I have a number of use cases where its extremely common to have optional things omitted. But I've not done an objective survey, so my WAG is not obviously any more useful than yours.

Comment: Systems I design avoid duck typing where possible, and use more formal typing/subtyping. You are certainly correct that polymorphism doesn't require defined types (or any types for that matter). But I believe it benefits from them enourmously.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you kindly for your suggestion about trying unevaluatedproperties; I will do so when I have the ability to switch to using a draft8+ compliant json schema scanner.

Comment: "OO" is a bit nebulous... JSON Schema seems to support many concepts found in OO ... it has extend (sounds like inheritance to me), composition, encapsulation, polymorphism... I'd also like to note that "composition over inheritance" does not mean "composition never inheritance" - not to suggest that it has been expressly implied. Inheritance just often makes good sense - of course you can shoot yourself in the foot where you haven't surmised the domain of possibility. I prefer to live in a world where you must be careful about how you use inheritance over one where it doesn't exist at all :)